# Does buildhive from CloudBees have JDK 7

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees, buildhive

Is JDK7 available on buildhive.cloudbees.com - I don't see it anywhere in the config?

Answer (score 2):

It seems this can be done with a Maven profile, use the following code in your `pom.xml` and add:

```
-Pbuildhive clean install
```

as Maven goal in BuildHive.

```
<profile>
      <id>buildhive</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.7</source>
              <target>1.7</target>
              <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
              <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
              <executable>/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0/bin/javac</executable>
              <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <jvm>/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0/bin/java</jvm>
              <forkMode>once</forkMode>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this workaround would not satisfy the Enforcer plugin, as can be seen here: https://buildhive.cloudbees.com/view/My%20Repositories/job/jenkinsci/job/winstone/15/console

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is available, even if not listed:

JDK 7 is located in: 
/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0

Go to the project configuration page and in the "Shell Script" put JAVACMD=/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0/bin/java ant tests -- for example

Comment: That does not help when you have a templatized job that does not allow specific configuration. For example https://buildhive.cloudbees.com/job/jenkinsci/job/winstone/configure does not have any place to set the JDK used to run Maven; and this job is in fact broken because it is run on JDK 6.

Comment: And why not make JDK 7 the default? You can easily use -source 6 and something like Animal Sniffer to build Java 6-based projects using JDK 7, but not the reverse.

Comment: yeah I think JDK7 should be the default.

Comment: JDK7 will shortly be the default