# How to change JDK version in Cloudbee Buildhive

Tags: cloudbees, buildhive

i am trying to created a build in CloubBees BuildHive. my maven is using 1.7 JDK and when i try to build i am getting following exception

```
 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
 [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
 [ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
 javac: invalid target release: 1.7
 Usage: javac <options> <source files>
 use -help for a list of possible options
```

Anyone tell me how to change the JDK version ?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [Does buildhive from CloudBees have JDK 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370158/does-buildhive-from-cloudbees-have-jdk-7) I think. It is on our to-do list to set JDK 7 as the default.